# The efficiency of Parcelable vs Reading from the database

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite, parcelable

I have a fragment that lists "Semesters" in the following way: It accesses the database, generates an array that is then translated into views via a `ListAdapter`.
In that fragment there is also an add button that opens a new activity, wherein the user can create a new semester that is also being inserted into the database in the same activity.

After creating a semester I obviously would like to show it when the user goes back to the list.
For that I have 2 options:

- Send the created Semester back as an object to the fragment. The problem is that it requires me to implement the `Parcelable` interface on most of my classes as they are nested, which would be really tedious.
- Make the list re-read the semesters from the database and recreate the view from scratch.

My question is; which way would be faster and more efficient?
Databases could get big overtime, but same for parcel objects, especially when they are nested and there are `List`s of custom objects and such, which makes this decision much more critical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parcels are super fast. It's essentially binary packed data and it's really memory and CPU efficient.

That said, it really depends on the size of the database. If it's relatively small (say, under 100 rows returned in the list query), I'd just requery it in onStart or onRestart. Makes everything much easier and more consistent. If that query takes noticeable time when returning to the list, I'd send it in the Intent.

Don't optimize  (by e.g. making everything Parcelable) without being sure the database access is the bottleneck.

Comment: Alternatively, (this is not a very good idea but it can be made robust), you can use a non-serializing event bus like Otto to pass the POJO from the create activity back to the list.

Comment: Thanks. This app is basically based on user input and therefore I can't forsee how many rows my database will have. But now that I think of it, I don't **always** need the nested objects (e.g I don't need the `Subject`s a `Semester` has until a user actually clicks on a `Semester`), so I could just set them to `null` or something and speed up the whole process even more. Also, now that I think about it, if `Parcel`s are that fast, they might be the better solution for me as I'd like to switch to an online database at some point, which would take even longer to query.

Comment: Do not use Parcels as permanent storage. Their format changes between Android veraions , so an upgrade can wipe all your users' data. As for the online database, try to "sync" it to all clients, if at all possible. Users hate querying online sources as it's super slow on a mobile connection.